# Leaflet: style using Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, leaflet

Hello i was working for a long time on a tiny weather website using leaflet.
The site show perfectly the Region, the departement and the city with their weather data from an API.
To access into the weather data, you click on a region then you select one of the department of the region than it show marker with data on it.

I want to add one last feature before i move on:
it's coloring the region or the department according to their global temperature.
The region have a color in their layer according of the global temperature of all his department.
and the department have a color in their layer according of the temperature of all his city.

The problem is the whatever temperature it is from the departement or the region, it's inside a promise.
Here is the code:

```
function getColor(temp) 
        {
            return temp > 50 ? '#8c1500' :
                temp > 40 && temp < 50  ? '#bf1d00' :
                temp > 30 && temp < 40 ? '#ff2600' :
                temp > 20 && temp < 30 ? '#ff5500' :
                temp > 10 && temp < 20 ? '#ffe100' :
                temp > 0 && temp < 10  ? '#0088ff' :
                temp < 0 ? '#0011ff' :
                '#ffffff';
        }


        function style(feature) // met en place la style
        {   
            feature.temperature_global.then(temperature => {
                return {
                    fillColor : getColor(temperature),
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    dashArray: '3',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                };
            });
        }
```

and here

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
            geojson = L.geoJSON(layer,{
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature 
            }).addTo(this.leaflet_map);
    
            resolve(geojson);
        });
```

it's in a method of a class **put_geojson_map(geojson,layer,tab_region)** put witch is called in the main by this fonction:

```
async display_map()
    {
        let geojson;
        let tab_region = this.Tableau_Region;

        if (this.Tableau_Region.length != 1) // si il y a plus qu'une Region dans la carte
        {
            for (region of this.Tableau_Region)
            {
                let geojson_Region = await region.get_Region_Shape("region");
                let geojson_Departement_Region = await region.get_Region_Shape("departements");
                region.set_geojson_Region(geojson_Region);
                region.set_geojson_Departement_Region(geojson_Departement_Region);
                region.créer_Attribut_Classe_Geojson();
                geojson = this.put_geojson_map(geojson,geojson_Region,tab_region); // on ajoute les zones des regions de paca dans la map grâce au GeoJSON que on récupére dans un fichier.
                region.get_tableau_Historique_Layer_Region().push(geojson_Region);
            }

        }
        else // si il y a qu'une seule Region
        {
            let geojson_Region = await this.Tableau_Region[0].get_Region_Shape("region");
            let geojson_Departement = await this.Tableau_Region[0].get_Region_Shape("departements");
            this.Tableau_Region[0].set_geojson_Region(geojson_Region);
            this.Tableau_Region[0].set_geojson_Departement_Region(geojson_Departement);
            this.Tableau_Region[0].créer_Attribut_Classe_Geojson();
            geojson = this.put_geojson_map(geojson,geojson_Region,tab_region);
            console.log(geojson);
            this.Tableau_Region[0].get_tableau_Historique_Layer_Region().push(geojson_Region);
        }
    }
```

Not the full code but it's the part that affect the style fonction for coloring the layer in the map.
Here **feature.temperature_global** is in every feature part of the layer and it's a promise.
how can i color the layer using the promise, i know i have to transform every part into a promise but it will bring forward the problem again and again.

How can i do it?
thanks in advance.